# React Native Expo console log didn't work any more

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo

i get an Error since yesterday. If i try any kind of debugging with "console.log"

```
  const response = await fetch(pickedImage.uri);
  const file_blob = await response.blob();
  console.log(response); // throw this error

  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      console.log(xhr.response); // throw this error
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', pickedImage.uri, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  // console.log(blob); // throw this error
```

This is the error message:

```
console.error: There was a problem sending log messages to your development enviroment. 
Error: value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. 
(In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')', 'value.hasOwnProperty' is undefined.
```

Please can anyone help me out i'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when trying to log the response of a fetch call. It happens because the response is too big to log. Only log the part of the response that you need. Also this error should not crash your app. You should be able to dismiss it and continue with your app.

Comment: Okay so there is no chance to log a response? And why i get an Error by logging an snapshot? `  storageRef.put(file_blob).on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    snapshot => {
      // console.log("snapshot", snapshot) // throw this error
    },
    error => {
      // console.log("uploadProfileImage Error", error); unsubscribe(); // throw this error
    },
    complete => {
      // console.log("uploadProfileImage", complete); // throw this error
    }
  )`

Comment: You can log just the data of your response or just the status not the whole response object. because it is too big. I never used Firebase and don't know what a Firebase snapshot is. But if it gives you the same error it is probably the same reason as with the response.